# Could a Kohen Gadol retire?

Tags: halacha-theory, kohen-priest

Related to this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74107/what-was-moshes-status-after-aharon-became-kohein-gadol).

Could a Kohen Gadol retire from his position?<sup>1</sup>

Despite [being old and blind](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.4.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Eli continued on as Kohen Gadol until his death. Could he have theoretically quit had he wanted to?

---

<sup>1</sup> by choice, not by being forced out of the position because of another factor such as a psilah or an ousting.

Comment: Kohanim in general retired when their hands and feet started to tremble ([Chullin 42b with Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.24b.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)). See also Rambam [MT Biat haMikdash 7:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008248/jewish/Biat-Hamikdash-Chapter-7.htm#v12).

Comment: Chabad writes "When a Kohen Gadol retired, became injured, or died, the Sanhedrin (the high Jewish court) would determine whether he had a son who was his equal in wisdom and fear of Heaven. If the son’s fear of Heaven measured up, he would be appointed even if he fell short in wisdom" and cites the Rambam Mishneh Torah, Klei Hamikdash 4:20 (but I don't see in the Rambam the notion of retiring).

Comment: Even if he can decide he can't do the YK avodah anymore, I assume he'd still have the kedusha of kohen gadol (can't become tamei for relatives etc.)

Comment: @Heshy I assume so too. I'd dint think that he'd be able to quit cold turkey.

Comment: Note that a kohen who temporarily replaces the kohen gadol cannot go back and become an ordinary kohen again. Thus we see that even if the kohen gadol retires, he still retains a greater degree of kedusha than a regular kohen.

Comment: If the Kohen Gadol wanted to retire, presumably he could posel himself and achieve his goal thereby (this is actually how Members of Parliament can quit their job in the UK- same process!) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resignation_from_the_British_House_of_Commons

Comment: @Zarka that sounds like a sin. Even if it isn't, it almost certainly isn't in the ruach of halacha. I'm wondering if there can be a retirement that's acceptable halacha-wise without any other contributing factors, such as shaky hands or a psilah.

Comment: Actually, a blind Cohen is disqualified from working - so how could he still have held the post of KG?

Comment: @DannySchoemann where does it say that? It was my understanding that if the KG is still able to slaughter and do other things - i.e. his *hands* still work fine (and if he's blind, he would be directed by another kohen), then that's okay. But aderabah, if it's not allowed, that provides useful insight into the text. It would mean that Eli was no longer KG at that point and was already replaced and at best, was only serving as shofet.

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bekhorot.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en that any blemish which disqualifies an animal, disqualifies a Cohen - see Mishna 5.5 that blindness is a blemish.

Comment: Apparently, this exists. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disqualifications_for_the_Jewish_priesthood @DannySchoemann it says here (though without a source...): "Kohanim with these blemishes would be allowed to perform work in the Temple outside of sacrificial service itself."

Comment: @Harel13 - correct. So we're back to square one.